# Is there any method to calculate confident score of a random Forest Regression (Continuous output) prediction in python?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, random-forest, statsmodels

I'm currently predicting the waiting time of a person at a location.

Test Input:

```
Location_Name  Arrival_Time
NSP            10:21:2019 05:10:01 PM
```

Output:

```
Wait_Time: 1 hr 32 min 27 sec
```

What I wish now, is to tell how confident(%) I am that this predicted output is correct.

In order to achieve it, I have tried Confident Intervals and score concept on Random Forest regressor but not able to achieve it.

predict_proba() function is not callable for regressor. So, I'm stuck with it.

```
#Python problem

print('------- Fitting the model ---------')
r_leg = RandomForestRegressor(max_depth=3, random_state=32,n_estimators=200,oob_score=True)

r_leg.fit(X_train,Y_train)

#define function to calculate rmse and print score
def rmse(x,y): return math.sqrt(((x-y)**2).mean())

def print_score(m):
  res = [rmse(m.predict(X_train), Y_train.to_numpy()),m.score(X_train, Y_train.to_numpy())]
#        if hasattr(m, 'oob_score_'): res.append(m.oob_score_)
  print(res)

print_score(r_leg)

def mean_confidence_interval(data, confidence=0.95):
    a = 1.0 * np.array(data)
    n = len(a)
    m, se = np.mean(a), scipy.stats.sem(a)
    h = se * scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2., n-1)
    return m, m-h, m+h

mean,LB,UB = mean_confidence_interval(Y_train.DayDiff)
```

The output should return the confident percentage like,

```
"I'm 80% sure that the person will wait at NSP for 1 hr 32 min 27 sec"
```

Comment: What do you mean "*not able to achieve it*"? What exact issue did you face with `mean_confidence_interval`?

Comment: By using mean_confidence_interval, I was able to get confidence ranges for 60,70,80,90,99(  i.e. 90% of the values lie between 5 minutes to 2 hrs) but it only defines the confidence range not confidence score. It tells that my output is lying under the confidence interval of 60% or 90% etc but i'm not able to achieve the confidence score of the predicted output.